# Hashing data at database layer or application layer

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, rdbms, database

I will take example of my case . I am using PostgreSql .I have gone through postgresql crypt() function documentation .

This function is provided as extension for postgresql .

If i migrate my data to another database by different vendor , Will the passwords still be evaluated properly or not ?.

If i try to compare the the hash generated in postgresql with hashing utilites provided by mysql/mongodb using same source string will it evaluate to be equal or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html), `crypt()`

> Calculates a crypt(3)-style hash of password. When storing a new
>   password, you need to use gen_salt() to generate a new salt value. To
>   check a password, **pass the stored hash value as salt**, and test whether
>   the result matches the stored value.

It means if you migrate your data to another database (if stored hash value is part of your data of course), the result of comparison will not depend on the system.

Comment: My concern is the cryptography function may differ across database .Will those hash values generated from postgresql  evaluate to the source data By the utilities provided by other databases

Comment: then update your question. when you tag postgres and say you want to move data to a different database, people think you mean you are moving data to a different postgres database. Please state clearly that you want to migrate  to a different vendor, not database

Comment: i have edited my question as you told but my doubt still remains uncleared

Comment: I don't know how other vendors implement it. After clarification my answer is useless here

Answer (score 0):

Can you move up the encryption/decryption to the application level? In that case,  you can migrate data as encrypted and other database vendor don't need to worry would consider them as normal data?

Another option is to encrypt disk level instead of applying encryption at a database level.

Answer (score 0):

After going through lot of posts it came to me that encrypting at application layer is better . like for example to encrypt passwords in java, we can use jBcrypt library   .